# How to read the gekko error code (e.g. Position : 5, v3 etc)

Tags: python, syntax-error, gekko

I got a syntax error in 'Position: 5'. I can't find the source of the error as not knowing where 'the Position 5' indicates. How can I recognize the problematic line in the original code by reading the error code? And, what does the v3 mean?

Error code

```
Exception:  @error: Model Expression
 *** Error in syntax of function string: Invalid element: <boundmethodgkvariable
 .dtof1>

Position: 5                   
 v3-(<boundmethodgkvariable.dtof1>)
     ?
```

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)

# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1)
x2 = m.Var(value=0)
u = m.Var(value=-0.75)

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Equations
m.Equation(x1.dt==u)
m.Equation(x2.dt==x1**2 + u**2)

# Objective Function
m.Obj(x2*final)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()

print(x1[-1], x2[-1])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `x1.dt()` and `x2.dt()` instead of `x1.dt` and `x2.dt`. The lack of parenthesis is causing the equation to not be evaluated correctly.

Once that is fixed, the model solves properly. Overall a confusing error, but a simple fix.